# Is there any c# web framework like Django or Ruby on Rails?

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, django

Is there any c# web framework like Django or Ruby on Rails? I know ASP.net MVC, but is seems not like Django, still got .aspx page and server side code on .aspx pages.

Is there some other c# web framework like django, pure html templates and c# code at back end side?

Thanks

Comment: You realise you don't have to have server side code on the MVC pages. Also, you can swap view engines to what your more comfortable with.

Comment: [Asp.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) is a good choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try MVC3. It has scaffolding and Razor View Engine which is much better and more htmlish than aspx